# Shell: adding a new line between a given line of text

Tags: text, shell, sed, awk, newline

What this question **isn't** asking is how to add a new line below or above every line which matches a pattern.

What I'm trying to do is add a new line between a pattern that exists on one line.

Here is an example.

*before:*

> Monday:8am-10pm

*after:*

> Monday:
>
> 8am-10pm

Thus in this case, insert new line after every 'Monday' pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/Monday:/&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo 'Monday:8am-10pm' | sed -e 's/^Monday:/&\n/'
```

For characters up to '`:`':

```
echo 'Monday:8am-10pm' | sed -e 's/^[^:]*:/&\n/'
```

Comment: This answer is more complete - I revised mine to use the & character after posting it.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/Monday:/&\n\n/g'
```

will replace them (supposing you want 2 newlines as shown above)

Comment: The 2 newlines was a mistake on my part. I meant for it to be just 1 newline. But you would be correct if that were the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo "Monday:8am-10pm" | sed -e 's/:/:\n\n/'
```

Comment: Looks like you messed up your line a little bit.